# Horizontal scroll size, how to prevent float left from wrapping

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, css-float

I have the folowing html and css :

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="scrollbox">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="subcontent">
                <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#scrollbox {
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    border:1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
#subcontent {
    width: 10000px;
}

#content p {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#scrollbox, #content p {
    height: 140px;
}
```

So i have a large horizontal `<div id="subcontent">` filled with `bla bla`. And i want it to be horizontal scrollable.

**Problem:** This solution works fine only in chrome. In others browsers the scrollWidth is 10000px. (in other words, the scrollbar is tiny and scrollZone too long)

Any other idea to make it work on all browsers ? And I'd like to get rid of my `width: 10000px;`.

[Here is a working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bBqkx/)

Comment: I don't understand why you have it set to 10,000 pixels wide in the first place.  Quote: _"I'd like to get rid of my width: 10000px;"_  So why not get rid of it then?  Not trying to be a smarty but it's not clear what/which end result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want the horizontal to be scrollable, just like the jsFiddle working example as it is now on chrome. The `width: 10000px;` is the only trick i have found to make a horizontal scrollbar (if you kick this width, the scrollbar disapear). I'd like to have the same scrollbar behaviour on every browsers, and i'd be glad if in your solution, you have no `width: 10000px;`.

Comment: fiddle won't appear for me.  However there are other ways of creating a nice horizontally scrolling div without an actual scrollbar.  http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html Check out this great jquery script.

Comment: @Jrod:  I would not recommend jQuery Tools as any viable long-term solution.  It has not bee updated for about a year (since jQuery 1.4.2), has issues with newer browsers (IE9), requires a ton of manual markup, it's not well supported and the developer has clearly lost interest.

Answer (score 0):

You set the overflow of x to scroll and the bar will always be present,

http://jsfiddle.net/bBqkx/4/

Comment: This is no good in Safari.  I see a ghost where the scroll-bar should be but the content simply re-wraps as I change the window width.

Comment: In firefox or chrome, i don't see any usable scrollbar. And in addition, the `p` elements seem to wrap on a new line.

Comment: have you tried using *white-space:nowrap;* for either the containing DIV or P?

Comment: @mendota doesn't work, all the text get stacked on the first line, and the `p` elements are still wrapped on new lines.

Comment: @Sparky672 a ghost of a scroll bar is still a scroll bar, there is just nothing to scroll to.

Comment: @Andrew: The OP wants a functioning scroll-bar, not wrap his content along with a non-functional ghost scroll-bar. There's no point of forcing a ghost scroll-bar if it never changes into a functional scroll-bar no matter how much content you add.

Comment: @Sparky672 in that case there is nothing he can do but set the width.